# How can I count the number of HTTP method calls in my REST API and put it into a database?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, http

I have a simple program that is supposed to get a user from github's API and I want to count the times the method is called.
Here is my REST Controller with a GET method (that's the method to be counted):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/info/{login}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable String login) throws IOException {
        userService.insertRecord(login);
        return userService.fetchUser(login);
    }
}
```

My program works (more or less) as it's supposed to, BUT .insertRecord() method does not work at all. It basically does nothing. The method SHOULD check if the database already has a user of the given login. If yes - then it should proceed to update the record and increment the REQUEST_COUNT number by 1. If no - then it should create a new record of a given login and REQUEST_COUNT as 1. The table in my database has only two column - LOGIN and REUQEST_COUNT.
But that method literally does nothing, the table in my database remains untouched.

```
public void insertRecord(String login) {
//this part checks if there is a login like that in the database already
        String sql = "select * from calls where LOGIN = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        ResultSet resultSet;
        try {
            preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, login);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
//if there's a result - I am trying to increment the value of REQUEST_COUNT column by 1.
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                String updateSql = "update calls set REQUEST_COUNT = REQUEST_COUNT + 1 where login = ?";
                PreparedStatement updatePreparedStatement;
                try {
                    updatePreparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(updateSql);
                    updatePreparedStatement.setString(1, login);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.error("Could not insert a record into the database.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//if there is no result - I want to insert a new record.
            } else {
                String insertSql = "insert into calls (LOGIN, REQUEST_COUNT) values (?, ?)";
                try (final PreparedStatement insertPreparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insertSql)) {
                    insertPreparedStatement.setString(1, login);
                    insertPreparedStatement.setInt(2, 1);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.error("Could not insert a record into the database.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Operation failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

No Logger's messages are printed either, it's as if the method was simply completely ignored.

Please, help.

Comment: Are you using microprofile? If so, [there is `@Counted`](https://www.tomitribe.com/blog/getting-started-with-microprofile-metrics/), which does counting but does not persist it to database. Upside: one annotation, and you are all set-up. Downside: counts are not persisted.

Comment: I don't think I am using microprofiles, I don't even know what that is :-/. Anyway, I need to find a way to store these records in my database.

Comment: Have you considered using `insert ... on duplucate key update ...` instead of the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not calling `updatePreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` !

The sql will only take effetc after you call `executeUpdate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a filter that will execute before/after the endpoint executed. And in that particular filter, you can also track which endpoint is executed and take appropriate action for any specific endpoint.